# When the boundary of a manifold is orientable?

Tags: general-topology, differential-topology

I am not sure whether the boundary of some manifold is definitely a manifold, but let's assume it is anyway.

Then in what case the boundary is an orientable manifold. Maybe when the manifold can be embedded into some orientable manifold? Thanks!

Comment: For $C^\infty$ manifolds, the boundary of an orientable manifold is always orientable.

Comment: One almost-but-not-quite tautological thing to say is that the boundary is orientable if and only if a collar neighborhood of the boundary is orientable.

Comment: If you're not sure if the boundary of a manifold is a manifold, perhaps you should worry about that before worrying about it being orientable. Note that the boundary of the non orientable Möbius band is the 1-sphere, which is orientable.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Thanks! What about the manifold, say M, is not orientable, but it can be embedded into some orientable manifold. In this case is the boundary of M is orientable?

Comment: @user330928 Every smooth manifold can be embedded in an orientable manifold, namely, Euclidean space.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Opps, forgive me.